# Find a monic quartic polynomial $f(x)$ with rational coefficients whose roots include $x=3-i\sqrt[4]2$. Give your answer in expanded form

Tags: polynomials

Find a monic quartic polynomial $f(x)$ with rational coefficients whose roots include $x=3-i\sqrt[4]2$. Give your answer in expanded form

---

Would I use some kind of factoring of $(x+y)^4$ I am guessing that there will a step to get rid of the imaginary value, and then a step to get rid of the irrational values, but I do not know how to approach this... Can someone please give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: what is $(x-3)^4 \; ? \;$

Comment: Use conjugates; e.g., multiply $3-i\sqrt[4]2$ by $3+i\sqrt[4]2$; but Will Jagy’s hint is better

Comment: $(x-3)^4=x^4+12x^3+54x^2+108x+81$ How does this help us...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
x&= 3 - i \sqrt[4]{2} \\
x-3&= -i \sqrt[4]{2} \\
(x-3)^4&= 2 \\
(x-3)^4-2&=0 \\
x^4 - 12 x^3 + 54 x^2 - 108 x + 79&=0 
\end{aligned}
$$

EDIT. In fact, you can even factor the given polynomial fully (if you desired) because examining the construction closely you can see the roots of $x^4 - 12 x^3 + 54 x^2 - 108 x + 79$ are precisely, $3 \pm i \sqrt[4]{2}$ and $3 \pm \sqrt[4]{2}$, i.e. $3 + \sqrt[4]{2} e^{2\pi ki/4}$ for $k=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: wow, thank you, this helps me understand how to do these a lot better.